# xhr requests hang on wikipedia and quore

Tags: networking, lubuntu, google-chrome, https

I've got two new ubuntu distributions, one lubuntu and elementary.io on different machines connecting via wi-fi through the same router.

Most internet things work fine but I can't submit forms on wikipedia or quora, using a variety of different browsers, chrome, firefox, midora. Looking at the network tab in chrome. It seems to be an xhr request which is hanging. On wikipedia I'm seeing a xhr request which is `(canceled)` after 30s. On Quora there is a number of xhr request which fail with 504 after 59s.

I've tried using a wired connection which make no difference.

The only suspicion I have at the moment is some problem with certificates.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be setting for the [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) which specifies the amount of data in internet packet. By default ubuntu uses a setting of 1500 for Eathernet packets. My router had a setting of 1492 for PPP and I needed to set the MTU to 1484 allowing some space bytes added by the various layers.

Some links which helped

http://www.microhowto.info/howto/change_the_mtu_of_a_network_interface.html

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-redhat-fedora-debian-linux-mtu-size/